# Reinvoking Vue.js html parsing

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I have template with some Vue.js attributes and binding. For example:

```
   <a v-on:click="loadAdditionalBusinesses()"
      v-if="!additionalBusinesses"
      class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">Load additional profiles</a>
  <div v-if="additionalBusinesses" v-html="additionalBusinesses"></div>
```

After clicking  tag i'm downloading from ajax **html alone**, not json data (because of reasons). This html contains some vue.js attributes like:

```
<a v-on:click="doSomething()">
```

Unfortunately, even though "doSomething" method is defined inside proper Vue.js Object and tag is nested in proper node it is not being invoked, because, as i suspect, Vue didnt parsed this html after that ajax call. 
Is there any way to 'reparse' such html?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to fetch arbitrary html and make Vue parse it as a template.

Comment: Not sure but worth trying: In your ajax's `Promise.then` ( if your ajax returns a promise )add this `this.$forceUpdate()`

Comment: @VAMSIKRISHNA it didn't work when I've tested this.

Comment: If `doSomething()` is defined in your code anyway, I believe this is a better approach to put template logic into a template (using `v-if`, etc.) - as intended. As far as I can tell right now, creating a (hopefully) dinamic component for this thing, hooking into its `render` function (to dinamically render given prop value as a template) haven't succeeded for me. Neither for binding `template` to this prop.

Comment: There was a question here that I can't find, but the gist was that you can create a new Vue instance and initialize it to use another instance's `$data`, methods, etc., effectively extending one instance to control new HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually i managed to succeed the task using this resource: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/679
 and v-bind:is attribute and mixing in component.